# iOS Video Not Playing

Tags: ios, video-streaming

First attempt to integrate video into an app. I've followed a couple of tutorials and also code from a book that I have, but I'm just getting a blank screen with no video (or anything else for that matter). I should also mention that I am attempting to run this in the simulator, if that matters.

I have `MediaPlayer.framework` linked as a binary library in my Build Phases. This is my code:

I can't understand what I am overlooking. Can anyone see it? Thanks!

MoviePlayerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MoviePlayerViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

MoviePlayerViewController.m

```
#import "MoviePlayerViewController.h"

@interface MoviePlayerViewController ()

@end

@implementation MoviePlayerViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{

//    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
//    
//    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
//                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
//                                                  object:player];
//    
//    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
//    {
//        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
//    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. However your link is not. I've tried opening it in a browser, and it has not loaded for a full 5 minutes. Try working with an offline, locally available video first.

Comment: @Tcharni the link works for me. And she's adorable, usr55410 :)

Comment: @LyndseyScott - yes, she is. I have no idea who she is, however! It's just a sample video.

Comment: Try presenting MPMoviePlayerController '[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with moviePlayer variable is iVar

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL.absoluteURL];
[self.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
[self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];

[self.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 240, 350);
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Try specifying the movie source type as streaming:

```
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

(2) Even though it's in fullscreen mode, I think you have to set an initial frame for your player, for example if you want it to take up the fullscreen:

```
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work, unfortunately. The second part had a `no visible interface` error. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, whoops, I meant [moviePlayer.view setFrame:... But glad to hear you found a working solution.